# Timestamp comparison in MongoDB not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to find documents that match the following conditions:

Both `updatedAt` and `item.lastItemDate` have a format that looks like this: `1681465291088`.

The value in the `updatedAt` field in MongoDB should be the latest time when compared to the time value in `item.lastItemDate`.

Currently, the filter is returning empty tasks consistently. What could be wrong with the filter?

The other `oneHourAgo` filter checks if the value was added at least one hour ago.

Please let me know if you need further clarification.

```
 const oneHourAgo = new Date(Date.now() - 60 * 60 * 1000);

      const Tasks = await ITasks.find({
        project: item.project,
        $and: [
          { updatedAt: { $ne: 0 } },
          { updatedAt: { $gt: new Date(item.lastItemDate) } },
          { updatedAt: { $lt: oneHourAgo } }
        ]
      }).exec();
```

Comment: "_a format that looks like this_" - meaning the value of the field is a number or a string? If so then your query won't work since you are comparing against dates

Comment: Mongo mode updatedAt is dates.now()

Comment: Please provide sample input data